# How to topological sort a sub/nested graph?

Tags: python, graph, python-3.x, topological-sort, subgraph

I've created a lightweight graph lib, which has 3 objects (Vertex, Edge, Graph) and 1 function (topo_sort), which looks like:

```
class DAGError(Exception): pass

def topo_sort(graph):
    sorted_list = []
    def visit(vertex):
        nonlocal sorted_list
        if vertex.idle:
            raise DAGError('Graph has at least one cycle.')
        if not vertex.done:
            vertex.idle = True
            for neighbor in vertex.vertices():
                visit(neighbor)
            vertex.done = True
            vertex.idle = False
            sorted_list.insert(0, vertex)
    queue = [vertex for vertex in graph.vertices() if not vertex.done]
    while queue:
        visit(queue.pop(0))
    return iter(sorted_list)
```

And this is working fine, if I have a flat DAG. But what I want to achieve is to add subgraphs *(or nested graphs)* into my main graph, as you can see in this illustration I draw:

[image: nested/sub graph illustration]

This is still a DAG, so if I ran my function on this, the *normal* `topo_sort` output is going to be something like this:

```
V0, V3, V1, V5, V4, V8, V7, V12, V11, V13, V14, V2, V6, V10, V9, V15, V17, V16
```

However my preferred output would be when all the vertices a subgraph depends on are *"processed"* before the vertices of the subgraph is processed -- so it should be something like this:

```
V0, V1, V8,        # vertices of maingraph
V3, V5, V4, V12    # vertices of subgraph_0
V7, V11, V13,      # vertices of subgraph_1
V14                # vertex   of subgraph_0
V2                 # vertex   of maingraph
V6, V10, V9, V15   # vertices of subgraph_2
V16, V17           # vertices of maingraph
```

But I could not find any resources on:

- how to "mark" or "store" a vertex in a graph as part of a subgraph?
- how to sort the vertices, based on their subgraph dependencies (as the example above)?
- how to get or process the subgraph as an independent graph?

I hope I could explain my problem detailed enough -- although if something is missing, please let me know, and I will extend my question with the missing parts.

Thanks in advance!

---

***EDIT:***

I found this [(Boost Graph Library, BGL)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/subgraph.html) and it looks like it solves a very similar *(or exactly the same?)* problem that I have, although, I'm not familiar with C++, so I don't understand how it is working and what exactly it is doing -- but I put this here, maybe someone will find it helpful to answer my questions..

---

***EDIT 2:***

I also accept pseudocode, not just python! Of course if an existed python library knows this, I'm interested in it, however, I don't want to use such a huge library as `graph-tools` for example -- that's why I created my own, so I prefer implementations more than libs.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late for you, but for other people with similar problems:

> how to "mark" or "store" a vertex in a graph as part of a subgraph?

Why not just give the vertex object an attribute `subgraph` holding an integer or a string labeling to which subgraph the vertex belongs? (If you want to use NetworkX, use the [node attribute dictionary](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#node-attributes))
This way, you can check this subgraph attribute in your sorting algorithm.

> how to sort the vertices, based on their subgraph dependencies (as the >example above)?

I'm not an expert on topological sorting, but asuming every vertex "knows" the subgraph it belongs to, this is what I came up with (using NetworkX, but you can easily implement the pieces I used in your own library): The code below gathers all the "dependencies" you described (all the vertices that need to come before the current one). You can use this information to modify your topol_sort() function in such a way, that it only appends the current vertex to the list if not all the vertices in its dependencies are already on the list.

```
import networkx as nx

# define the graph and the subgraphs suitable for NetworkX
G = ...
subgraphs = ...

for subgraph in subgraphs:
    # find all vertices that the current subgraph depends on
    dependencies = set()
    for vertex in subgraph:
        anc = nx.ancestors(G, vertex) # anc is the set of all vertices having a path to 'vertex'
        dependencies.union(anc)
    dependencies -= subgraph.nodes()
    # store these dependencies under every vertex of the current subgraph
    for vertex in subgraph:
        G[vertex].node['depends'] = dependencies

# run modified topological sorting
topo_sort_mod(G)
```

> how to get or process the subgraph as an independent graph?

I'm not sure what you exactly want here. Maybe [this](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.subgraph.html?highlight=subgraph#networkx.MultiDiGraph.subgraph) helps (again, using NetworkX), especially this part:

> To create a subgraph with its own copy of the edge/node attributes use: nx.Graph(G.subgraph(nbunch))
>
> If edge attributes are containers, a deep copy can be obtained using: G.subgraph(nbunch).copy()

I hope this helps anyone ... :)

Answer (score 0):

read your statement about Graph-tools but still not sure if you like to use a library to do a certain job or you like to understand how to write it yourself.

Maybe you look at

```
General Samples
[http://networkx.github.io/examples.html][1]

DAG Example
[http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.6/_modules/networkx/algorithms/dag.html][2]
```

and see if it helps you to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @Peter -- I already knew `networkx`, but I did a recheck on it, and eventhough I read [all the articles mentioning the word 'subgraph'](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/search.html?q=subgraph&check_keywords=yes&area=default) it seems, that networkx doesn't have the features I'm looking for (or at least, not that I'm aware of) -- although it has a `subgraph()` method, but it only re-referencing a part of the graph, which doesn't effect the sorting algorithm. Anyway, thanks again, but none of these links were helpful..(BTW I prefer to understand and implement this on my own)